# Get string between two sub strings; second sub string ignored

Tags: python, regex

I have the string:

```
a = '/imo:9615169/mmsi:373239000/vessel:ALAM%20MUTIARA'
```

Using regex,

```
result = re.search('imo:(.*)/', a)
print(result.group(1)) #prints 9284764/mmsi:354662000
```

Why does this print `9284764/mmsi:354662000` instead of just `9284764`?

Comment: Because `*` is a greedy quantifier matching as many chars as possible. When usign `*?` lazy quantifier, you'd get your required value.

Comment: use "\d" instead of "."  -> result = re.search('imo:(\d*)/', a)